# Call AuthorizeAttribute only once

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization

We have created our own authorize attribute that inherits from the `AuthorizeAttribute` in MVC. This is added at the controller level. We use the attribute to populate the principle on the thread.

This method is ran each time with the user being retrieved from the cache or the db.

```
public void AuthenticateAs(System.Web.HttpContextBase context, IPrincipal user) {
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = context.User = user;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(((Entities.User)((SiteIdentity)user.Identity).User).Locale);
        }
```

We have noticed though that when we have a view that has a number of `RenderAction` calls that the attribute is called multiple times.

Is there any way to stop this happening i.e. when the view calls a number of `RenderAction` methods then the initial IPrincipal is used?